# Android: Autocomplete for multiple input

Tags: android, autocomplete

For my app, I'm trying to get the autocomplete suggestion box to pop up for multiple inputs in the textbox.

For example, let's say the input is "Alice, Bob, Charlie". The user begins to type in "Alice" and selects the name from the suggestions, updating the text view with "Alice, ". Then the user types in "Bob" and the suggestion box pops up again, so the user clicks the name and the text view updates to "Alice, Bob, ". And so on.

The default AutoCompleteTextView in Android doesn't seem to support that kind of functionality of having the suggestions box pop up for each input, only for the first input. How do I go about having the suggestion box pop up for each input?

Comment: You can use a database for this prediction purpose. For each keypress run a query to find matching words and show them to the user for selection just like a softkeyboard does.

Comment: Well, I'm using AutoCompleteTextView to do the suggestions box thing, with all the strings stored in strings.xml. Is there no way to extend AutoCompleteTextView to work on substrings of the text box instead of the whole box or am I going to have to manually recreate all this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, had to use MultiAutoCompleteTextView instead of AutoCompleteTextView.